# How to keep track of letters already guessed in Hangman game for C++?

Tags: c++

This assignment given to me was to copy a Hangman game from our textbook and modify it to specific instructions in the book. I have spent a lot of hours trying to research this issue and find a reason why I keep getting the same error message that I do. Everywhere I have looked, everyone that have attempted to modify this code have attempted with arrays and have had the same luck that I have. I'm currently doing a chapter in Strings and was planning on doing most of my statement that is requested by the instructions in String.

What I need to modify in this code is to:

1. Keep track of all letters that are input by the user
2. Send an error message to the user if they input a letter that is already entered

The main issue I am having is that when I compile this code and put in the same letter that I have already put in, it terminates with the message:

**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out of range'
    what(): basic_string::substr**

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

        //declare variables
        string origWord = " ";
        string letter = " ";
        char dashReplaced = 'N';
        char gameOver = 'N';
        int numIncorrect = 10;
        string displayWord = "-----";
        string usedLetter = " ";
        string letterNotGuessedYet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        int letterPlace = 0;

        //get original word
        do //begin loop
        {
            cout << "Enter a 5-letter word in uppercase: ";
            getline(cin,origWord);

        }while(origWord.length() != 5); //end do loop

        //clear the screen
        system("cls");

        //start guessing
        cout <<"Guess this word: " << displayWord << endl;

        while(gameOver =='N')
        {
            cout << "Enter an uppercase letter: ";
            cin >> letter;

            //This provides the letterPlace value with the possition of the 
            //input letter by the user within letterNotGuessedYet
            letterPlace = letterNotGuessedYet.find(letter,0);

            //This statement determines if the letter input by the user is
            //still in the letterNotGuessYet string.
            if(letterNotGuessedYet.substr(letterPlace,1)== letter)
            {
                letterNotGuessedYet.replace(letterPlace, 1, "*");
                //cout << endl << letterNotGuessedYet;           //This tests that a letter is being replaced with an * 
            }                   
            else
            {
                cout << "The letter " << letter << " has already been used. Choose another letter." << endl << endl;        
            }// end if


            //search for the letter in the original word
            for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {
                //if the current character matches
                //the letter, replace the corresponding
                //dash in the displayWOrd variable and then
                //set the dashReplaced variable to 'Y'
                if (origWord.substr(x,1) == letter)
                {
                    displayWord.replace(x, 1, letter);
                    dashReplaced = 'Y';
                }//end if
            }//end for

            //if a dash was replaced, check whether the
            //displayWord variable contains any dashes

            if (dashReplaced == 'Y')
            {
                //if the displayWord variable does not
                //contain any dashes, the game is over
                if (displayWord.find("-",0) == -1)
                {
                    gameOver = 'Y';
                    cout << endl << "Yes, the word is " << origWord << endl;
                    cout << "Great guessing!" << endl;
                }

                else //otherwise, continue guessing
                {
                    cout << endl<< "Guess this word: " << displayWord << endl;
                    dashReplaced = 'N';
                }//end if

            }
            else //processed when dashReplaced contains 'N'
            {
                //minus 1 to the number of incorrect gueses left
                numIncorrect += 1;

                //if the number of incorrect guesses is 10,
                //the game is over
                if (numIncorrect == 10)
                {
                    gameOver = 'Y';
                    cout << endl << "Sorry, the word is " << origWord << endl;

                }//end if
            }//end if
        }//end while

        //system("pause");
        return 0;
    }//end of main function
```

I believe the reason that I'm receiving this error has something to do with the below code:

```
        //This provides the letterPlace value with the possition of the 
        //input letter by the user within letterNotGuessedYet
        letterPlace = letterNotGuessedYet.find(letter,0);

        //This statement determines if the letter input by the user is
        //still in the letterNotGuessYet string.
        if(letterNotGuessedYet.substr(letterPlace,1)== letter)
        {
            letterNotGuessedYet.replace(letterPlace, 1, "*");
            //cout << endl << letterNotGuessedYet;           //This tests that a letter is being replaced with an * 
        }                   
        else
        {
            cout << "The letter " << letter << " has already been used. Choose another letter." << endl << endl;        
        }// end if
```

I am grateful for any assistance that you can bring my way.

Comment: The problem is using the return value of the `std::string::find` function without testing it. The problem is using the return value of the `std::string::find` function without testing it. Its [return value](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) can be a special value `npos` if the substring is not found.  If you use that value in `substr`, it is in an invalid index, which leads to the exception you see.

Comment: A good time to learn about debugging is now. SO is not a debugging service. You need to do this part yourself. Start your debugger, instruct it to stop at exeption throwing sites, examine your variables, find out which one is an out-of-bounds index of which array,  figure which logic error is leading to this condition, fix, repeat. If you have a problem getting your debugger up and running and doing what you want, ask a different question.

Comment: Thanks NicholasM, that link and your explanation helped me understand what was going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is because you are using the "letterPlace" value before you test to see if it was actually found or not. If "string::find" doesn't find anything it will return a value "string::npos". You need to test the letterPlace vairable for this value before trying to use it.

```
letterPlace = letterNotGuessedYet.find(letter,0);

// Check to see if this letter is still in the "letterNotGuessedYet string
if(letterPlace != string::npos)
{
    // At this point the letter is in the letterNotGuessedYet string so let it go
    letterNotGuessedYet.replace(letterPlace, 1, "*");
}
else
{
    // The letter was not found which means it has already been guessed.
    // Show error to the user here
    cout << "The letter " << letter << " has already been used. Choose another letter." << endl << endl;
}
```